# Algebraic Geometry: Proving a mapping between variables and their polynomials is a bijection between their vanishing loci

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I understand homework problems are discouraged but this is a problem from algebraic geometry I have no clue how to proceed in and was wondering if someone could give me hint

Let $R$ be a commutative ring. Denote by $\Bbb A_{m}^{r} := R^n$ and call it n-dimensional affine space over $R$. Let $A$ be a finitely generated $R$-algebra, with a surjective $R$-algebra homomorphism: $$\pi:R[x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n] \longrightarrow A$$
sending $x_i$ to $a_i \in A$.

Let $J := \ker(\pi)$ define the vanishing locus of the ideal $J$
as the set $$V(J) := \{ (r_1, \dots, r_n) \in A_{n}^{r} : f(r_1, \dots, r_n) = 0 \forall f \in J\}. $$

Likewise, $\pi ':R[y_1, y_2, \dots, y_m] \longrightarrow A$ is another surjective $R$-algebra homomorphism sending $y_i$ to $b_i \in A$. Let $J' := \ker(\pi ').$

Denote by $p: \Bbb A_{m}^{r} \longrightarrow \Bbb A_{n}^{r}$ the map

$(r_1, r_2, \dots, r_m) \mapsto (p_1(r_1, r_2, \dots, r_m), p_2(r_1, r_2, \dots, r_m), \dots, p_n(r_1, r_2, \dots, r_m) ).$

Prove that $p$ restricts to a bijection between $V(J') \cong V(J)$.

My attempt to show it was injective and surjective needs more justification. I'm asking for a solution just guidance on where to go.

My attempt:

Injective:
Assume $P(r_1, \dots, r_m) = P(s_1, \dots, s_m)$

Then $(P_1(r_1, \dots, r_m), \dots, P_n(r_1, \dots, r_m) ) = (P_1(s_1, \dots, s_m), \dots, P_n(s_1, \dots, s_m))$

Then $P_i(r_1, \dots, r_m) = P_i(s_1, \dots, s_m)$

So, $r_i = s_i$.

I'm not sure how to show surjectivity.

Comment: Do we know anything about $p_i$?

Comment: I don't see how this could possibly be true in general. What if $p$ is the zero map? What if $p$ maps exclusively to values outside $V(J')$? There must be some restriction on the kind of map that $p$ is in order for this to make sense.

Comment: "Denote by $\mathbb{A}_m^r := R^n$" doesn't really make sense. The left-hand side depends on $m$ and $r$ but the right-hand side depends on $n$.

Comment: You need to give more information about how the map $p$ is defined in order to make progress here. In fact, your argument for injectivity assumes that the $p_i$'s themselves are injective, which is not necessarily true without knowing more about these component functions.

Comment: in the previous question, we proved that the map                                                     $s: R[x_1, \dots, x_n]/J \longrightarrow  R[y_1, \dots, y_n]/J'$, explicitly $s: x_i + J \mapsto p(y_1, \dots, y_m) + J'$ is well-defined and an R-algebra isomorphism.